# CodeIgniter app doesn't work when domain has "www"

Tags: codeigniter, php

What things in CI or my server do I need to set so that my application will work with the "www" domain prefix. Everything works as intended -- as long as there is no "www". With the "www", I get all sort of errors (e.g. DB connection, etc.).

Comment: copy/paste your errors is not hard, and it will greatly improve your chances of getting meaningful help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check your config.php or .htaccess file(s) if you have them.

Comment: base_url() was not set correctly. Thanks.